# Django order_by Capital Letters Sorting before Lowercase

Tags: django

When I sort in Django I found this odd, I made a four records with the following **titles**:

- AAAA
- aaaa
- ZZZZ
- zzzz

When I sort it eg:

```
messages = messages.order_by('-title')
```

Why do I get the following results? It's as if the capital letters take precedence:

- AAAA
- ZZZZ
- aaaa
- zzzz

Comment: What result are you expected? `'Z'` is less than `'a'`.

Comment: Could this giveyou some ideas? http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2007/11/20/case-insensitive-ordering-with-django-and-postgresql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behavior indeed. Capital letters have precedence over lower case letters. I think is probably because of the [`ascii` code](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) of capitals is lower than lower cases'.

Try this in a console:

```
>>> x = ['a','A']
>>> sorted(x)
>>> ['A','a']
```

Hope this helps!